# yii - insert data into two tables via single form

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I am very much a novice with PHP and the Yii framework.

Click here to see a sample of my SQL database setup https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6qQj.png

I have set up controllers and models for all three tables and have set up CRUD views from Gii for the Users table. I have read through this -> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/ and tried multiple sets of code examples etc... and failed. The best I can do is get the create form to insert all the data into the users table but not the email table. I believe my short coming is in my UsersController.php -> public function actionCreate() section. Can someone help me out with a sample piece of code to make the information post into the email table?

---EDIT---
As requested below is the requested info...

UsersController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Users;
        if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
                $model->password=crypt($model->password,'salt');
                $model->datecreated = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
            if ($model->save()) {
                $modelEmail = new Email;
                $modelEmail->attributes = $_POST['Email'];
                $modelEmail->fer_users_id = $model->id;
                if ($modelEmail->save())
                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            }
        }
        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

This is the users/_form.php view file:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'users-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstname'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstname'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastname'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastname'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx(Email::model(),'emailaddress'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField(Email::model(),'emailaddress',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error(Email::model(),'emailaddress'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'fer_roles_id'); ?>
                <?php
                        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'fer_roles_id', 
                        CHtml::listData(Roles::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'description'),
                        array('class' => 'my-drop-down', 'options' => array('2' => array('selected' => "selected")

                                    )
                                )
                            );
                ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: you have to make an instance of your models first, and then add your attributes to your models, after that you must save.. what are the names of your models?

Comment: Names of models are "Users", "Email" & "Roles".

Comment: please upload your view code...

Comment: also upload your action controller code..

Comment: Just a note I have tried reversing the FK to see if I can get the code to work with no luck... just trying anything at this point!

Comment: sorry for taking long, your error might occur on your model, check your rules on the model

Answer (score 2):

you could do this:
Controller:

```
<?php

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Users;
    $model1 = new Email;

    $roles = Roles::model()->findAll();

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        $model->password = crypt($model->password, 'salt');
        $model->datecreated = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        $model->save();

        $model1->attributes = $_POST['Users']['emailaddress'];
        $model1->fer_users_id = $model->id;
        $model1->save();

        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'user'=>$model,
        'email'=>$model1,
        'roles'=> $roles
    ));
}

?>
```

your view:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'users-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($user); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($user,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($user,'username',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($user,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($user,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($user,'password',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($user,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($user,'firstname'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($user,'firstname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($user,'firstname'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($user,'lastname'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($user,'lastname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($user,'lastname'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($email,'emailaddress'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($email,'emailaddress',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($email,'emailaddress'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($user,'fer_roles_id'); ?>
                <?php
                        echo $form->dropDownList($user, 'fer_roles_id', 
                        CHtml::listData($roles, 'id', 'description'),
                        array('class' => 'my-drop-down', 'options' => array('2' => array('selected' => "selected")

                                    )
                                )
                            );
                ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($user->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

if you get any error with this, let me know..

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't recognise the email address and keeps generating this error... http://i.stack.imgur.com/4svWU.png